# absolute value binomial split into two absolute values

Tags: absolute-value

$$
 |a-b| = |a|-|b|
$$

I think I might missing something with absolute values. Can I split a binomial into two separate absolute values like above?

Comment: you can do it always when $a\ge b>0$

Comment: so if both a and b are positive and a is greater than or equal to 0

Comment: Or if $a\leqslant b\leqslant0$.

Comment: Thankyou guys, I assume there is no reason why the first constraint cannot be 0 such as $a \geqslant b \geqslant 0 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. For example, Let $a=1$ and $b=-2$. We have $|a-b| = |1-(-2)| = |3|=3$. On the other hand, we have $|a|-|b| = |1|-|-2| = |1|-|2|=1-2=-1$. Clearly, $3 \neq -1$.

It is, however, true that $||a|-|b|| \le |a-b|$. In fact, we can extend this:

$$||a|-|b|| \le |a-b| \le |a|+|b|$$

Comment: if you include Battani comment above then this would be correct.

Comment: The inequalities are valid for all $a$ and $b$. Your original post did not include the conditions $a \ge b > 0$, and I can only answer the question you ask.

Comment: No it does not contain those conditions in my question, nor have I subsequently added them. I believe the constraints help answer my question as it seems there are some cases where this equality works as described by Battani and now Did. This is what was confusing me originally. Your answer is correct in the general sense so I think you should add in the special constraints before I can mark as correct.

Comment: Ah I just wrote this out on a white board with a table of combinations {1,0,3,5} and understand what you mean now. What I was asking for is actually already in the second part of your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No. Breaking $|a-b|$ up like that is no good. Try $a = 1$ and $b = 2$. Your equation is true if $a \geq b > 0$.